# Can't ssh in Raspberry PI from Manjaro

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi, openssh, manjaro

I'm able to ssh into pi from MacOS using `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` or `ssh pi@ip_address`. I have been doing this for a long period of time. Now I installed Manjaro Linux along with the MacOS but I can't ssh in pi from Manjaro. `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` returns `name not found` error while the other command times out. Works as expected when I switch back to MacOS. I've been stuck on this for a while now, I've tried multiple solutions but nothing seem to work. I have also tried re-installing and starting sshd but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the Network adapter driver. If you are facing this problem check which driver are you using. If it is anything other than the Broadcom driver delete it and install the Broadcom driver and should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the information of /var/log/message on Raspberry PI, where the problem has been checked